# Uncaught Reference error in Titanium

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile

I'm having trouble with including functions from another file.
I have 2 files `app.js` and `responsive.js` in responsive.js i have this:

```
    // 100%
    var per100 = Math.floor(Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth * 1.0); 
    // 90%
    var per90 = Math.floor(Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth * 0.9); 
    // 80%
    var per80 = Math.floor(Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth * 0.8); 
    // 60%
    var per50 = Math.floor(Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth * 0.6); 
    // 50%
    var per50 = Math.floor(Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth * 0.5); 
    // 40%
    var per40 = Math.floor(Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth * 0.4);
    // 25%
    var per25 = Math.floor(Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth * 0.25); 
    // 10%
    var per10 = Math.floor(Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth * 0.10); 
    // 5%
    var per5 = Math.floor(Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth * 0.5); 
    // 1%
    var per1 = Math.floor(Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth * 0.1);
```

and in the `app.js` file i have this:

```
// include needed files
Ti.include('responsive.js');



//Create the screen

//The home screen
var homeWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({
  exitOnClose: true,
  fullscreen: false,
  title: 'Advanced'
});

var homeView = Ti.UI.createView({
  backgroundColor: 'white'
});

var homeLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    top: 20,
    left: 30,
    height: 30,
    text: 'Login or register to start',
    color: 'black',
    font: {fontSize: 18}
});

var homeLoginButton = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title: 'test',
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    top: 55,
    left: 30,
    width:per60,
    height: 30,
    color: 'black',
    font: {fontSize: 14} 
});

var homeRegisterButton = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title: 'test2',
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    top: 55,
    left: 180,
    width:per60,
    height: 30,
    color: 'black',
    font: {fontSize: 14} 
});

//Creating the application
//Home screen
homeWindow.add(homeView);
homeView.add(homeLabel);
homeView.add(homeLoginButton);
homeView.add(homeRegisterButton);
homeWindow.open();
```

everything is pretty easy but every time I try to start the application I get this error

```
Uncaught Reference error: per60 is not defined
```

How can i solve this issue?

Comment: so where is the `per60` in your `responsive.js`?

Comment: The width of the homeRegisterButton has the per60 var

Comment: @The_Monster: Why you have given Answered at bottom of your question? If the answer of Olivier helped you, you just need to accept the answer!! If your self resolved the issue, you can answer for your own question instead of editing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have twice:

```
var per50
```

and no

```
var per60
```

in your first file